# How does my computer know to which character a char corresponds?

Tags: fonts, operating-system

Does my OS load a font file which maps the UTF-8 codes to characters(the way to render it ) when I start up my computer?

Since there are a lot of different fonts, the font files will consume a lot of memory?

Or the font files are stored in hard-disk and are only loaded in to the memory when needed?

Just a question that comes into my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is called encoding. The encoding is completely seperate from a font. The header of a file tells the OS (or reading program) which encoding the file uses(ex. ASCII or UTF-8). This encoding is how the computer knows what sequence of bits map to what characters.

Font files determine how the text looks. Time New Roman, Arial are examples of fonts. These fonts are stored on the hard-disk and are very small, almost irrelevant on any modern machine.

Does this help?

Edit: [The wikipedia page may be more clear...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

Comment: Yes, it helped me. But once the reading programe knows that a squence of bits correponds to a certain character, the rendering(how a character looks) work depends on the font file? What does a font files do?

Comment: Exactly as you said, the font file determines how the character is represented on screen. It has nothing to do with what the character actually is in memory.

Comment: So in the font file there should be a mapping between characters(with a certain encoding) and the way to render each character?

Comment: Exactly, though it's a little more complex. For example, in some languages, how a character is represented depends on the characters around it

Comment: Wow, interesting! Coud you please recommande me some web sites or book so that I can know more about this filed? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar any good sources. I think I'd just start with the wikipedia page I linked and go from there.